# How to add subdomains in heroku in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, subdomain

I have an app in ruby on rails which have multiple subdomains which on localhost are like this

```
manager.daycare.no:3000/
worker.daycare.no:3000/
daycare.no:3000/
admin.daycare.no:3000/
parent.daycare.no:3000/
```

Now I want to add these on heroku. How I add these sub domains on heroku?

My heroku-app name is `sufa-travels.herokuapp.com/`

Comment: did u configure it locally first ?

Comment: I update my question

Comment: Do u have `daycare.no` domain already ?

Comment: i have updated my post, look at that

Answer (score 2):

As I know, you cannot choose specific ports for configure your host in Heroku, also Heroku not supports DNS. But you can add custom domains and subdomains, and from your domain hosting settings, redirecting to Heroku app. Here is little shot from youtube [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sf6GhsVGcTQ)

Heroku Doc says: [Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#custom-subdomains)

```
$ heroku domains:add www.example.com`
Adding www.example.com to example... done
>
$ heroku domains:add blog.example.com`
Adding blog.example.com to example... done
```

Comment: I do this heroku domains:add blog.example.com
But when I run blog.example.com it doesn't work

Comment: @haseeb 1st of all, you have to buy yr domain from domain hosters for example 'haseebe.com' then after getting domain u have to add it to Heroku with command above like 'heroku domains:add haseebe.com' once u add it. There link to youtube it show you everything check that one!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a subdomain by using the `heroku domains:add` command.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-domain-with-a-subdomain

Comment: I  do this heroku domains:add blog.example.com But when I run blog.example.com it doesn't work

Comment: Try logging into your Heroku dashboard on heroku.com and check if your domain is listed under the "Custom Domains" section. If so, your next step will be to add the DNS Target to your domain provider. The process varies depending on whoever you have purchased your domain from.