# My CNAME domain not showing my web app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

I have set a custom CNAME using the instructions found on Heroku at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#view-existing-domains. My dns target has been changed and currently points to Heroku, additionally in the settings it says that my app is available at my domain, and using the `host example.com`, it shows the the confirmation that my app and domain are connected. However, when I visit my domain, I get a default page from Heroku, not my site. I can't find any instructions that say I need to modify my push location, and I am stumped. Domain is http://www.rockforestlabs.com

Thanks for your insight in advance.

Comment: Did you add "www.rockforestlabs.com" as well as "rockforestlabs.com"?

Comment: Thank you, I went into the settings and added both and it shows up under www.rockforestlabs.com but not rockforestlabs.com. I guess I need to redirect traffic from rockforestlabs.com to www.rockforestlabs.com.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create in the hosting subdomain named `www`. And redirect your main `rockforestlabs.com` to subdomain named `www.rockforestlabs.com`.

In the link attached Youtube video also.

[How to add subdomains in heroku in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437632/how-to-add-subdomains-in-heroku-in-rails/36437678#36437678)

Answer (score 0):

The problem resolved itself once I added both domains example.com and www.example.com. Here is a good link that helped, after I found it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bBg8ab4wAXo